# How to apply a LEFT() or TRUNCATE to this SELECT query which uses a DISTINCT?

Tags: sql-server, truncate

How do I apply a trunc or left to this query?

My current Query;

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT processname
FROM table
WHERE status = 'Aborted' 
    AND logdate > 1671981354000 
GROUP BY processname
ORDER BY processname ASC
```

I've tried the following;

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(processname, 5)
FROM table
WHERE status = 'Aborted' 
    AND logdate > 1671981354000 
GROUP BY processname
ORDER BY processname ASC
```

However this results in the following error code;

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

I am not quite sure how I would fix this query, do any of you folks have an idea? Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**
So to answer a few questions I see in the comments, my query does have an Alias to the select, but I left it out in this example when I removed the actual table and column names because I didn't know that you were able to Order by the Alias, so I thought it to be irrelevant.

I've now changed the Query to;

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(processname, 5) AS 'processnamealias'
FROM table
WHERE status = 'Aborted' 
    AND logdate > 1671981354000 
ORDER BY processnamealias ASC
```

Also this query is quite a lot bigger than just this example and I wasn't the one that created it, just the one that wanted to 'fix it' so I didn't reall question the Group by in there as well.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Order by LEFT(processname, 5)  or the questionable approach  Order by 1

Comment: Why are you using a `GROUP BY` *and* `DISTINCT`? A `GROUP BY` already returns the data in *distinct groups*; having a `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` in the same query scope is only a sign of a flaw. But why are you using a `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation?

Comment: Skipped right over the Group By

Comment: Can you add an alias to your column? Example: `SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(processname, 5) AS processname` . ORDER BY is executed after the SELECT clause, so you can explicitly reference aliased columns.

Comment: I must admit, as well, the error is pretty specific here; what about the error don't you understand and we can *try* to elaborate.

Comment: So to answer a few questions I see in the comments, my query does have an Alias to the select, but I left it out in this example when I removed the actual table and column names. Also I didn't know that you were able to Order by the Alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the error, you can see that the `ORDER BY` clause must match the `SELECT` clause. You are altering the `processname` column in the `SELECT` clause but not carrying that alteration to the `ORDER BY` thus they are not the same.

Remember that the `ORDER BY` clause is executed **`AFTER`** the `SELECT` clause, thus you can reference aliased columns in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(a.processname, 5) AS processname_alias
FROM (SELECT '123456789' AS processname) a
ORDER BY processname_alias ASC
```

This is effectively the same as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(a.processname, 5) AS processname_alias
FROM (SELECT '123456789' AS processname) a
ORDER BY LEFT(a.processname, 5) ASC
```

I also removed your `GROUP BY` because it is not needed.

**Final SQL:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(processname, 5) AS processname
FROM table
WHERE status = 'Aborted' 
    AND logdate > 1671981354000 
ORDER BY processname
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know you could reference the alias name with order by. Makes sense though. Thanks for the explanation.